# How can I release a Maven module independently from other modules?

Tags: maven, multi-module

I have a Java web application (GLF) which has the following structure

```
GLFBuilder (multimodule)
- GLFCoreBuilder (multimodule)
  - GLFCore (depends on other core/library projects)
  - GLFDataModel
- GLFWebBuilder (multimodule)
  - GLFFrontEnd
  - GLFFrontEndWeb
  - GLFIntegration (to create app war)
```

All the submodule projects listed above share the same parent at the moment (e.g `GLFFrontEnd` is child of `GLFWebBuilder`, `GLFCore` is child of `GLFBuilder`...) to be able to share common configuration/dependencies.

I also configured `dependencyManagement` to include all the submodules with appropriate properties defined so that I don't have to specify `version`'s anywhere in the submodules inter-dependencies.

I should mention that all the modules (multimodules AND submodules) all share the same SNAPSHOT version at the moment and (sigh) my company still releases the app using SNAPSHOT versions to avoid dealing with version numbers, but among all the problems this brings it also considerably increases the build times in our CI environment.

I'd like to be able to release a stable version (no SNAPSHOT) one of the modules independently from the others.
This sounds logic considering I can change something in `GLFFrontEnd` which doesn't have anything to do with my core libraries.

I know that when there is a parent-child relationship children cannot be released as stable (no SNAPSHOT) without releasing the parent too which has a "chain effect" over the projects hierarchy.

Is maven release plugin suitable for this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: First what kind of problems brings it to have a multi module build apart from a hight build time? Furthermore about what build time are we talking about?

Comment: @khmarbaise the problem is that everything at the moment is versioned as SNAPSHOT.  
This way maven has to always rebuild everything from scratch on every release when we run our pipeline, regardless from what we effectively change or not.

Concurrency and build reproducibility are other problems steaming from SNAPSHOT versions too.

My question was anyway pretty related to releasing modules independently.

Comment: If you have correctly configured your multi module build you can reproduce the state via your version control system. I don't understand where is the problem with build reproducibility...The question is: If you like to release single modules of your multi module build alone it might be the time to remove them from the multi module build and make them stand a lone...and what do you mean by concurrency ? And in the end you can release a module separately using the release plugin but I would recommend to reconsider this....

Comment: The build reproducibility does not depend on SCM. In the dependency graph you can have a dependency on other library projects which could even not live in the same SCM repo, and if they are in SNAPSHOT when you build the project you can't guarantee that they remain the same on every run.
Still, my question was about the possibility to release sub modules independently so can you please detail the reasons why releasing a sub module with maven release plugin should be reconsidered?

Comment: Ok..If you have other dependencies outside your reactor than I understand your problem...which means for me you should use releases only...or maybe you need to think to integrate them into your multi module build...